# Is it possible to simultaneously have a sortable grid and moving objects between grids?

Tags: reactjs, drag-and-drop, react-dnd

I have a screen like shown in the picture below (excuse my excellent MSPaint skills). I need to be able to move the cells in between grids (i.e. Cell 1 from Grid 1 to Grid 2) and simultaneously having the ability to sort the cells within a single grid by dragging them to the wanted place (i.e. Moving Cell 6 in Grid 1 in before Cell 1).
I'm using react-dnd. I was trying to achieve that by having the cells as both a DropTarget and a DragSource and the grid as a DropTarget but it never recognized the drop in the cell, only the drop in the grid.
So is it possible doing this in this library? Or in any library really?
Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Yes, it possible with react-dnd! https://codesandbox.io/embed/gracious-wozniak-kj9w8

Comment: The library is not at all documented, things are not working with no errors. It's really not useable.